# NextJS Dynamic Routing - Is it possible to set array of route names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

I'm using dynamic routing in my app. Here is the folder structure I'm working with

```
-pages
  -department
    -[slug].js
```

Now I want to show the page if only the slug value is `cse, eee, swe, english e.t.c` otherwise I want to show the `404 Not Found` page. Is there any way to set the array of route names ? Then, if slug value(which I can get using `getServerSideProps`) is included in that array, I will serve the page otherwise serve the `404 Not Found` page.

**Why I need that ?**

In `getServerSideProps` function, I'm getting data from api end-point. In this case if slug value is not included in the api-endpoint, server throws `Request failed with status code 501` error!
So if slug value is `cse`, the api-endpoint is available and I can get the data. If slug value is `anything or xyasdfs`, the api-endpoint is not available and I can't get the data and the server throws the following error.

Answer (score 0):

i would check in my component for a property in my response body.. like, if all the departments have a name,, then check for it, if it doesn't exist, then return a 404.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this to render from server side

```
Page.getInitialProps = async ({query}) => {
  if(query.slug == 'cse') {
    //codes
  }
}
```

or you can use next Router hook
https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: I do it manually comparing the slug value, but I'm looking for a better solution.